# Regex delete some text with start and end. eg(::Temple::Utils.escape_html)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In Rails ,I convert slim to erb, got too match useless text

```
<tr class="highlight">
    <td><%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((cloud_file.name)) %>
    </td><td>
    <div class="input-append">
        <%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((text_field_tag '', cloud_file.asset.url, :class => :span4)) %>
        <%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((link_to 'check', cloud_file.asset.url, :target => :_blank, :class => :btn)) %>
    </div></td><td><%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((number_to_human_size(cloud_file.file_size))) %>
</td><td><%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((cloud_file.content_type)) %>
</td><td>
<%= ::Temple::Utils.escape_html((admin_delete_button(cloud_file))) %>
</td></tr>
::Temple::Utils.escape_html((cloud_file.content_type))
::Temple::Utils.escape_html((l))
```

I just want delete `::Temple::Utils.escape_html((...))`  and keep the text between parenthesis `((...))`. eg("cloud_file.name")

Here is mine regex,Not work.

```
::Temple::Utils.escape_html\({2}(?<=[^.*])\){2}
```

How did fix it? thx

Comment: Like [`gsub(/::Temple::Utils\.escape_html\({2}(.*?)\){2}/m, '\1')`](https://ideone.com/HEUdbZ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
gsub(/::Temple::Utils\.escape_html\({2}(.*?)\){2}/m, '\1')
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HEUdbZ) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR4hV0/1).

You used a lookbehind `(?<=[^.*])` instead of a consuming subpattern `.*?`. You may adjust the pattern and replacement pattern to include one set of parentheses or add quotes at both ends of the capture group #1 (the part captured with `(...)`).

Comment: Correct,But I also want to know ,may I get this in sublime text directly

Comment: You have not tagged it with Sublime Text, but in fact, you can use `(?s)::Temple::Utils\.escape_html\({2}(.*?)\){2}` there with `\1` replacement pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm.

Comment: Just FYI: a lookbehind is not consuming characters, that is why your pattern only tried to match strings that had a character other than `.` or `*` at the position after `((` (and there is a `(` - so your lookbehind always returned true), but after that, your pattern only consumed `))` - and there was not such a text in your string (like `::Temple::Utils.escape_html(())`). That is why you needed `.*?` - match any character, 0+ times, as few as possible.